# how to post the data through api in android and show the data in python web interface

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

I'm new to python-flask. i created the end points by using restless api ,my question is ,while posting the data through android app the data will not be inserted to the API. here what is the problem .

Comment: What do you mean by **data will not be inserted to the API**??

Comment: i have database models in flask framework  and create the http methods to endpoints by using restless api. here my problem is while posting the data through android app ,it showing error.

Comment: Please update the question with the error, It will help better understand your question

Comment: can you suggest any document for this question.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Comment: i am appreciating you, but in flask how to pust it to server the API has to accept images.

Comment: do i change any code in API.

Answer (score 1):

Files in flask request can be accessed via the `request.files`

```
@app.route("/api/imgupload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    file = request.files[<input-name>]
```

Comment: this question is ,i asked 2 days ago.

Comment: i'm unable to understand the code.